# Auth0 under SSR

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering, auth0

I have the below hook in my code, to do Auth0 redirects for me. For the most part, it is an example that Auth0 people published at one time, along with their `@auth0/auth0-spa-js` library.

```
const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);

export const Auth0Context = createContext();
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context);
export const Auth0Provider = ({
  children,
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  ...initOptions
}) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [auth0Client, setAuth0] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initAuth0 = async () => {
      const auth0FromHook = await createAuth0Client(initOptions);
      setAuth0(auth0FromHook);

      if (
        window.location.search.includes('code=') &&
        window.location.search.includes('state=')
      ) {
        const { appState } = await auth0FromHook.handleRedirectCallback();
        onRedirectCallback(appState);
      }

      const isAuthenticated = await auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated();

      setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        const user = await auth0FromHook.getUser();
        setUser(user);
        localStorage.setItem('user', user.email);
        const token = await auth0FromHook.getTokenSilently();
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };
    initAuth0();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const loginWithPopup = async (params = {}) => {
    setPopupOpen(true);
    try {
      await auth0Client.loginWithPopup(params);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setPopupOpen(false);
    }
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setUser(user);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };

  const handleRedirectCallback = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setLoading(false);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUser(user);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        loading,
        popupOpen,
        loginWithPopup,
        handleRedirectCallback,
        getIdTokenClaims: (...p) => auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(...p),
        loginWithRedirect: (...p) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p),
        getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
        getTokenWithPopup: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(...p),
        logout: (...p) => auth0Client.logout(...p)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

This code is working fine, only for `history` and `location`, it uses `window.history` and `window.location`. Due to this fact, the code does not work under Server-Side rendering.

I need this function for a few different reasons, starting with:

```
const App = () => {
  const { loading } = useAuth0();

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect
        from='/:url*(/+)'
        to={
          typeof window === 'object' && window.location
            ? window.location.pathname.slice(0, -1)
            : '/'
        }
      />
      <Route exact path='/' component={Deals} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path='/draft' component={Draft} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path='/cabinet' component={Cabinet} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
      <PrivateRoute
        path='/deal/:id'
        exact
        component={(props) => <Draft {...props} />}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

I do have history for the context, so I just need a way to pass it to the `useAuth0` function.

```
const { store, history } = configureStore();

const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');
const AUTH0_SCOPE = 'openid profile email';

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
  history.push(
    appState && appState.targetUrl
      ? appState.targetUrl + (appState.qs || '')
      : window.location.pathname
  );
};

const Application = (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <CookiesProvider>
      <Auth0Provider
        domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
        audience={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE}
        scope={AUTH0_SCOPE}
        client_id={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
        redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
        onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      >
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Frontload noServerRender={true}>
              <App />
            </Frontload>
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
      </Auth0Provider>
    </CookiesProvider>
  </Suspense>
);
```

Any ideas how to rewrite this function using something similar to `useLocation` and `useHistory` hooks from `react-router-dom`, or something else to get `useAuth0` working on SSR?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the modern `@auth0/auth0-react` library already implements `useAuth()` in a way compatible with SSR. Way to go Auth0!